# Computing offsets of a 2d array in MIPS ASM

Tags: assembly, mips

Lets say I have a 2d array of ints with a size 36:

```
 game_board:   .space 36
```

The game board is a 6 x 6 sudoku board, broken up into 3x2 boxes:

```
0 0 0 | 0 0 0
0 0 0 | 0 0 0
-------------
0 0 0 | 0 0 0 
0 0 0 | 0 0 0 
-------------
0 0 0 | 0 0 0 
0 0 0 | 0 0 0
```

I'm using a brute force method to solve the puzzle, and need to be able to investigate each cell and do some computation. In order to do this, I believe I need to compute the offsets for each cell location.

What I've tried so far (seen from an example) is to do the following:

```
 move $s0, $zero    # Begin at position 0
 li   $s1, 6        # Load $s1 with board size
 div  $s0, $s1      # Cell Offset / Board Size
 mflo $s2           # $s2 = cell row index
 mfhi $s3           # $s3 = cell column index
```

At this point, I'm unsure how to use $s2 and $s3 with game_board in order to get to the cell I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The snippet you provided clearly won't work as you are dividing zero with 6 which clearly results in zero.

I'd suggest you write a helper routine which, given the base address of the board, row length, and desired row an column returns the address of the desired cell.

E.g.:

```
.data
game_board:   .space 36
.text
    la $s0, game_board
    li $s1, 6
    li $a0, 1
    li $a1, 2
    jal cell_location
    # Upon return $a3 contains address of cell

# $s0: board game base, $s1: row length (number of columns per row), $a0: row, $a1:col
# Return $a3: cell location
cell_location:
  sll $a3, $s1, 2     # row size
  multu $a3, $a0
  mflo $a3            # row base offset
  sll $a1, $a1, 2     # column offset
  addu $a3, $a3, $a1  # cell offset
  srl $a1, $a1, 2     # restore column number
  addu $a3, $s0, $a3  # cell location
  jr $ra
```

Comment: I appreciate the assistance. I'm not familiar with the instructions sll, multu, addu, or srl. What exactly are they accomplishing and is there another way to accomplish it without using those instructions?

Comment: @TalenKylon: My advice would be to read at least the MIPS assembly instruction set, sll (shift left logical), multu (multiply unsigned), addu (add unsigned), srl (shift right logical). Generally speaking there are dozens of ways to program an algorithm, however this snippet in particular isn't using any tricks so you should try to understand what it's doing (the source is already commented)

Comment: The main reason I ask is that for this particular project I am not permitted to use pseudo-instructions except for a select few that have been specified by the instructor. So I just want to make sure that I do not violate the rules! I will certainly follow your advice and read the MIPS documentation on these instructions. I'm sure I'll be back with questions!

Comment: @TalenKylon: The code in the cell_location routine does not use pseudo instructions. The only pseudoinstructions used in my example are `li` and `la` which I guess you are allowed to use

Comment: Understood. So if I wanted to modify the value at a cell location ,or get a value at that location I would just do something like:

      move    $t0, $a0       # $t0 = cell location
      lb          $t1, 0($t0)   # get value at cell location
      sb         $t2, 0($t0)   # assign value to cell location

Comment: @TalenKylon: If you use the routine of this answer then after calling it you would have in `$a3` the cell address. So to read that value into `$t1` you could issue `lb $t1, 0($a3)` and to store the value in `$t2` into the cell you would issue `sb $t2, 0($a3)`